# html upload image to div not working on mobile properly

Tags: javascript, canvas

So im trying to upload an image to a canvas background, i have that working with an upload tag but when you use this on mobile it turns the photo on the side.

**HTML**

```
<input class="button" type='file' id='getval' name="background-image" />
```

has anybody ever come accross this before and if so please help.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
document.getElementById('getval').addEventListener('change', readURL, true);
function readURL() { 
    var file = document.getElementById("getval").files[0]; 
    var reader = new FileReader(); 
    reader.onloadend = function() { 
        document.getElementById('paint').style.backgroundImage = "url(" + reader.result + ")";
    }; 
    if(file) { 
        reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
    } else {}
}
```

Comment: Post (and format) this code in the question, not in comments.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask please reffer

Comment: thanks just re-formatted it.